# Is it possible to get the Return to Castle Wolfenstein prequel maps on the PC?

Tags: mods, return-to-castle-wolfenstein

In the [PS2 and Xbox versions](http://wolfenstein.wikia.com/wiki/Return_to_Castle_Wolfenstein#Ports) of the game, (Subtitled *Operation Resurrection* and *Tides of War* respectively), There are a few Prequel missions based in a small town and ancient catacombs in Egypt.

Feeling nostalgic, I just installed the Steam version, and was a little disappointed that these prequel maps were missing (I didn't know they were prequel maps at the time).

I've been looking high and low, but haven't been able to find any info on getting these maps. Is there a mod or DLC I can install to play them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research on the subject.

All that i could find was this:

> I was quite disappointed when I realized that there is no communitiy remake of this mission for PC. There are quite some user made missions available for download, but not this official one. I tried doing it myself, but with no success. Cinematics weren't a problem. PS2 edition uses PSS format, and Xbox edition uses BIK format. Both of them can be easily converted to whatever format PC requires. As for maps, this waren't the case. In PC edition, maps are packed into PK3 format, which is actually renamed ZIP archive. As for PS2, it uses RDF format, and Xbox uses CACHEMAP format. I did quite extensive googling and, unfortunately, wasn't able to find a way to unpack those. I came to conclusion that only way to play that mission is to play it on the actual console, either PS2 or Xbox.

... quote from user Eqagunn from this wikia talk page http://wolfenstein.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Return_to_Castle_Wolfenstein

It seems that you only have 2 options, one realistically:

- you can emulate the ps2 version with the pcsx2 emulator. The game should run fine on a modern system with a better resolution even.
- extract the PS2 files. The game engine should use similar map files and model/texture data to the formats used by the PC game engine, but as stated by Eqagunn on wikia, the extraction process can be hard or non existent most probably because of proprietary archiving formats. Let's not forget that the console could be limited compared to the PC data files, data corruption, engine restrictions etc.
- there is a slim chance that somebody already managed to do this and release a mod of it. Haven't found anything in my searches. Maybe some daring modding team is developing a copy of the prologue missions on moddb, so give that site a try, I may have missed them, but highly unlikely.

In conclusion, the only practical solution is to emulate the PS2 version. The XBOX version could be trickier. There is an emulator in it's infancy because of even bigger softwarehardware restrictions, so slim chances of extracting those data files altogether.
Maybe a petition for a director's cut to the game's devs could be made.

Hopefully this answers your question partially about making this available for PC.

Comment: Thanks Shmukers, you outdid yourself here! Yeah I've considered using PCSX2, although IIRC it in itself is a bit of a pain to set up. Might be my only option though. I'll leave the bounty open for the time being, to try and draw more attention to it (and hopefully, a modpack :P)

Comment: Thanks! The PCSX2 compatibility lists say the NTSC version of the game is playable (best rating). It should work fine out of the box. Yeah, it can be a pain to set up custom render settings like AA or custom resolutions. Trial and error kinda gets to you after the 20th try. Hopefully, someone knows at least SOMETHING about some elusive mod team :/

Comment: I'm currently emailing id software/zenimax as well. I'd like to hear an official response, even if it is "Our legal team are the Grinch that stole Wolfenstein Christmas" :P

Comment: Isn't Activision the major publisher? Wikipedia says it's either them or Valve. Valve's Steam store page says it's id. Weird. If it's Activision we're talking about, I don't think they'll consider this an option unless there is some big cash throwing going around.

Comment: @Smukers - [id software](http://www.idsoftware.com/games/wolfenstein/) published the game back in the day, but they've been bought by Zenimax (who owns Bethesda and a few others as well). I don't know what Activision's stake is

Comment: No response from Id/zenimax at all, and I haven't been able to find any more info.